# $ sign in a Text widget , how to show special characters in flutter? how to set special character to text widget in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, special-characters, dollar-sign

I am trying to write a $ sign in a Text

```
Text("Refer and Win 10 000 $")
```

I get an error

[image]

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: I've never used flutter, but have you tried escaping the dollar sign character? It might have a special meaning. Try `Text("Refer and Win 10 000 \$")`

Comment: @DavyM It's also possible to use raw strings `r"Refer and Wind 10 000$"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Davy M mentioned, you have to escape the `$` because it's used as a control character for embedding variables in a string.
See the Dart docs: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#strings

Comment: you reference the docs without answering the question..... One can use the '\' character to escape in flutter --> '\$' will allow you the include the $ character within your string

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Runes` class which does not need any plugin

**Example**

You want to show Dollar sign and you know its unicode value ie `U+0024`

Now to show it in text you can use `Runes` class and convert it to show `Dollar sign ($)`
 Just need to use the unicode value after `U+` ie `0024` and then append it with `\u`

**Usage**

```
Text(new String.fromCharCodes(new Runes('\u0024'))),
```

[List of special characters](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0024)

Comment: One can use the '\' character to escape in flutter --> '\$' will allow you the include the $ character within your string

Answer (score 0):

You can use \ prefix to doller sign  in text widget`Text("\$ 50")`